# Assembly: Not Executing Commands After Boot Signature

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

My operating system's boot sector literally reached 512 bytes and I do not have enough space for my codes. I wrote some code after boot signature but they did not work. I put code to shutdown but it did not work. Why the codes after boot signature do not work?

Code:

```
BITS 16

disk_buffer equ 24576

mov sp, 4096d
mov ax, 7c0h
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 09h
mov cx, 1000h
mov al, 20h
mov bl, 17h
int 10h

jmp shutdown

;codes that off the point

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xaa55

shutdown:
mov ax, 5307h
mov cx, 3
mov bx, 1
int 15h

times 1474560 - ($ - $$) db 0
```

Comment: *I wrote some code after boot signature but they did not work.* The BIOS only loads the first 512 bytes of the disk into memory because that's how the system is designed; there's no mechanism to tell it how much more to load, you have to write code to do it yourself.  See answers to [How to fix "os.asm:113: error: TIMES value -138 is negative" in assembly language](//stackoverflow.com/q/53858770) for how to make the actual bootloader load more code.

Comment: Do I need to use `int 13h`'s `ah=02h` service?

Comment: *Need* is a strong word.  You could write a floppy driver that uses in/out instructions directly.  But I think the *easiest* thing would be to follow the example in that linked answer which uses `int 13h / ah=2` to read sectors from a floppy.

Comment: How I will use it? There are arguments like sector number, low eight bits of cylinder number. I am new to Assembly and OS programming.

Comment: [How to fix "os.asm:113: error: TIMES value -138 is negative" in assembly language](//stackoverflow.com/q/53858770) explains lots of details and has links to more, and has a full working example.  Got read it; I'm not going to re-type Michael Petch's answer for you in comments!  And google anything else you don't understand.

Comment: @PeterCordes I used Michael Petch's codes and compiled it with NASM but I got `VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR` error from VirtualBox. Do you know this error or its solution? This happens to me when I use binary files that includes other binaries.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use that 512 bytes to load the rest of your code. That is it's purpose, hence the name "boot record".

If you are writing your operating system code in the MBR, you are doing it in the wrong place. THe way that most operating systems do it is in three (or more) phases. First, your MBR code loads a simple boot loader from disk into ram. The MBR code then jumps to the location it loaded the bootloader into and begins executing the boot loader. the boot loader does some system initialization, then loads either a second stage boot loader or the operating system into memory and then jumps to that memory to begin booting the operating system.

from [osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/MBR#MBR_Bootstrap) wiki

> An MBR is loaded by the BIOS at physical address 0x7c00, with DL set
>   to the "drive number" that the MBR was loaded from. The BIOS then
>   jumps to the very beginning of the loaded MBR (0x7c00), because that
>   part of the MBR contains the "bootstrap" executable code.
>
> Typical MBR bootstrap code will do the following:
>
> -relocate itself away from the 0x7c00 physical address (using a memory copy, and usually a far jump)
>
> -determine which partition (or hard disk) to boot from (either by looking for the active partition, or by presenting the user with a
>   selection of installed operating systems to choose from)
>
> -if the user selected an "inactive" partition, then set the selected partition entry to "active", and clear the "active" bits of other partition entries
>
> -use BIOS INT 13h commands to rewrite the MBR if the partition table entries were modified
>
> -use BIOS INT 13h commands to load the Volume Boot Record (VBR, the "bootsector" of the bootloader) from the beginning of the selected
>
> partition to physical address 0x7c00
>
> -set DS:SI pointing to the selected partition table entry
>
> -jump to 0x7c00 (with CS set to 0, and DL set to the "drive number")
>
> Note: it is intended for the value of DL, and the DS:SI pointer to be
>   passed all the way into the kernel, for the kernel's use. This also
>   means that the relocated MBR should not be overwritten during the boot
>   process -- because the DS:SI pointer is aimed at a partition table
>   entry inside that MBR, and needs to remain valid.